# CodeIgniter unable to get Ajax data into variable

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have an Ajax post from a js file. This all works, but I am not able to set data to a variable and echo this to the screen.

I guess I do not know how to set class variables?

get Ajax code:

```
public function get_info()
{
    // $test = $this->input->post();
    var_dump($this->input->post());  
    $original_property_text = $this->input->post('original_property_text');
    // set_ajax($original_property_text);
    //$new_property_text = $this->input->post('new_property_text');

    //return $test;
}
```

class variables and constructor:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    // gobal vars
    var $new_property_text = '';
    var $original_property_text = '';
    var $changes = array();

    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //$changes[] = $this->get_info();
    }
```

*** edit *****

ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'users/get_info',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'original_property_text': $original_property_text,
        'new_property_text': $new_property_text
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data); // for testing
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: show your ajax code pls

Comment: you need to echo something in get_info()

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, use this in your PHP :

```
public function get_info()
{
    // better to use json when you need to return array
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $this->input->post() );
    exit();
}
```

In your ajax code (using jQuery framework) :

```
// call your controller in ajax
$.post('yourUrlHere', $('#yourForm').serialize(), 
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // you manipulate json, so you can use : alert(data.property);' 
    }, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

'$' defines variable so convert your php value to javascript object.

```
data: {original_property_text: '<?=$original_property_text?>', new_property_text: '<?=$new_property_text?>'},
```

Or,

```
var original_property_text = '<?=$original_property_text?>';
var new_property_text = '<?=$new_property_text?>';
var base_url = '<?=base_url();?>';

$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'users/get_info',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {original_property_text: original_property_text, new_property_text: new_property_text},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data); // for testing
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And Get Using Your get function

```
print_r($_POST);exit
```